# How do I rotate vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, rotations

It's given vector $\vec{e_{1}}=0.31\vec{e_{x}}+0.95\vec{e_{y}}$. How do I rotate that for 30 degrees counterclokwise? What I have done, I have used $x’=x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta$, $y’=x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta$, but I'm not sure if get right solution.

Comment: Check to see if $\vec e_i \cdot \vec e'_i=\cos(\pi/6)$ for $i=x,y$.

Comment: It's correct.  To convince yourself, try drawing a picture.

Comment: @Dr.MV What exactly theta should be?

Answer (score 0):

Given a point $p=(x,y)$, you can rotate it $\theta$ degrees to get a point $\tilde{p}$ by using the rotation matrix $R\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ via
$$
\tilde{p} = Rp = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which rotates $p$ counterclockwise by $\theta$ degrees.

Notice that your results are exactly as given here :)
Check out [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) too.